# Jquery datatable plugin not working on html table

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, datatable

I am trying to use the DataTable plugin to add functionality to my html table. I followed the steps for installation and initialization from datatables.net, but it is not adding any functionality to my html page. I am wondering if it is because my table is formatted in a way that isn't supported by the plug-in. Any input would be useful. Thanks a lot!

Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>{% load staticfiles %}
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#detailTable').DataTable();
    });
</script>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static  'inventory/detailStyle.css' %}" />-->

<h1>{{ inventory.inventory_name }}</h1>

<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="detailTable">
    <thead>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>STATUS</th>
        <th>DERIVATIVES</th>
        <th>SUBSYSTEMS</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>{% for block in inventory.block_set.all %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ block.block_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ block.block_status }}</td>
            <td>{{ block.block_derivatives }}</td>
            <td>{{ block.block_subsystems }}</td>
        </tr>{% endfor %}</tbody>
</table>
<div>   <a href="{% url 'inventory:requests' inventory.id %}">Request  Form</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some error of javascript?

Or your code have this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min"></script>
```